# What is the minimal visual studio subscription eligible for VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

My question is about the minimal level of a Visual Studio Subscription that is eligible for Visual Studio Team Services. From what I understand you need a Visual Studio Subscription (previously MSDN Subscription) to be able to access VSTS online but someone told me you need the full Enterprise subscription, which I find a bit hard to believe. Is this really true or can you access it with a Professional as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need *any* Visual Studio Subscription to use VSTS: it's [free for five users](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/pricing/) independent of any Visual Studio Subscription.

Beyond the first five users, you can purchase individual per-user licenses. 
 A license is *also* included with Visual Studio subscriptions.  So if you have a Visual Studio Professional Subscription, that will enable [the standard features](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/compare-features/) of VSTS.

There are additional features enabled to Visual Studio Enterprise subscribers:

- [Private pipelines](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.build-release-private-pipelines)
- [Package management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.feed)
- [Test manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web)

But all other features are available to the free and Visual Studio Professional subscribers.

Answer (score 2):

VSTS is free of cost initially for 5 user's, called Basic User Access.

In detail, VSTS provides with 5 Basic user access, unlimited Visual studio subscriber access and on top of it all other's[Non-Visual studio Subscribers] get restricted to Stakeholder access [No access to code].

Find the access comparison [Basic vs Stakeholder Access](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/compare-features/)

[Article to add users/Visual studio Subscribers to VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/add-account-users-from-user-hub)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking to develop in VS, but another IDE, you can also just buy the User CAL for Basic code access https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-vstsuser